# Bash - list files within date range

Tags: bash, shell, sh, ls

I'm trying to list files last modified in july of this year, with bash.

So far I've been basing my efforts around [this blog](http://www.aramiskenderian.org/journal/2011/03/25/linux-how-to-delete-files-in-specific-date-range/)`*` and have come up with:

```
startdate=”201407010000?
enddate=”201408010000?
touch -t $startdate ./startdatefiles
touch -t $enddate ./enddatefiles
find ./ -type f -newer ./startdatefiles ! -newer ./enddatefiles -ls
```

I get the following error:

```
touch: invalid date format `201408010000?'
```

Does any one know of a straight forward way to do this?

**EDIT :**

`*` N.b. The blog has since been updated

Comment: I think your problem is that you are terminating the startdate and enddate with `?` instead of `"`.

Comment: Why are there question marks at the end of startdate and enddate? Try to replace the question marks with double quotes and run it again.

Comment: Thanks, I've done that. It's still not working - will update with details.

Comment: The starting quotes in your pasted code were not ASCII. Quotes are not necessary in this situation.

Comment: @qingbo - thanks that was it. #rookieerror. If you put as an answer I will accept.

Comment: Thanks also @RedX and nicky_zs - that was half of the problem.

Comment: Ah, the old dumb smart-quotes syndrome: software that insidiously replaces normal ASCII quotes with fancy opening and closing quotes. And it looks like the blog software got the smart-quotes around the wrong way, since the quotes at the start of those date strings look like closing quotes, not opening quotes. :facepalm:

Comment: duplicate of http://superuser.com/q/817575/4714

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow the blog post got the code messed. Quotes must be ASCII quotes and should be paired in assignment value:

```
startdate="201407010000"
enddate="201408010000"
```

Actually since the value (timestamp) doesn't contain spaces, quotes are not necessary here. It can be written:

```
startdate=201407010000
enddate=201408010000
```